# Return each unique instance of value in an array, in a new array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to write a function which would take in the following array,

```
var data = [
            {
                name: 'Josh',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Gold'
            }, 
            {
                name: 'Bill',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Platinum'
            },
            {
                name: 'Gary',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Platinum'
            },
            {
                name: 'Phillip',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Platinum'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bob',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Gold'
            },
            {
                name: 'Barry',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Gold'
            },
            {
                name: 'Joe',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Gold'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ed',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Silver'
            },
            {
                name: 'Baxter',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Platinum'
            },
            {
                name: 'Patrick',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Silver'
            },
            {
                name: 'Stepehn',
                description: 'some data about this guy',
                sortOrder: 'Silver'
            }
];
```

and give me an array which looked like this:

```
[Platinum, Gold, Silver] <-- The order doesn't matter
```

So it would check all `sortOrder` values in the array and return an array containing one instance of each unique `sortOrder`.

Anything I've written so far keeps giving me multiple instances of each `sortOrder`.... Could anyone give me a hand?

I have access to the underscore.js library if that can be of any help.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq ? -> `_.uniq(_.pluck(data, 'sortOrder'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var result = _.chain(data)
  .pluck('sortOrder')
  .uniq()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/bu6nw2zy/)

Answer (score 3):

This should work great (clean js):

```
var orders = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    if (data[i].sortOrder && orders.indexOf(data[i].sortOrder) == -1){
        orders.push(data[i].sortOrder);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is preventing multiple adds of the same value here? Repeating `if ('foo' && !orders['foo']){
        orders.push('foo');
    }` keeps adding to `orders`

Comment: @PaulS. it shouldn't. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @YavorIvanov—`orders[data[i].sortOrder]` is checking *orders* for properties **named** *Gold*, *Platinum*, etc. but they are values within the array, not names of properties. This just creates an array of all the *sortOrder* values, duplicates included. Perhaps you missed the part "*…return an array containing one instance of each unique sortOrder.*".

Comment: @PaulS. OMG :D I'm kinda ashamed. You're right thanks :D I'm really sleepy

Answer (score 2):

With underscore :

```
console.log(_.chain(data).pluck('sortOrder').uniq().value());
```

Answer (score 1):

As the values are *String* we can go via an *Object* in *vanilla JavaScript*

```
var a = (function (arr) {
    var i, o = {};

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        o[arr[i].sortOrder] = true;

    return Object.keys(o);
}(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any other library:

```
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
    if(results.indexOf(data[i].sortOrder) < 0){
      results.push(data[i].sortOrder);
    }
}
```

The `results` variable would contain the list you want.

Comment: You don't need a special case for `.length === 0`, _indexOf_ will give `-1` still

Comment: True.  Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote the first part.   Edited to take that out.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of plain JS offerings, which are always good to compare with libraries. Consider using ES5's reduce:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  if (acc.indexOf(val.sortOrder) == -1) acc.push(val.sortOrder);
  return acc;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'd use a `Set` to ensure the `sortOrder` stays single-entry. You can use the spread operator to place it back into an Array if that's the data structure you need. You don't have to write a new function or a lot of logic to check if an entry exists this way, though you could wrap the whole thing in a function if it is something you need to reuse a lot.

```
const result = [...new Set(data.map(({ sortOrder }) => sortOrder))];
```

Or as a function:

```
const getAllSortOrders = (data) => [...new Set(data.map(({ sortOrder }) => sortOrder))];
```